# Do I have to sanitize user input with prepared SQL statements?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is this considered completely safe?

```
$stmt = $dbhandler->prepare("update sometable set somefield=:somestring");
$stmt->bindParam(":somestring",$_REQUEST["hack_me_please"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

And if not, what could make it safer? I'm assuming there are unknown vulnerabilities in PDO/MySQL/PHP that may be exploited in the future so I'm wondering if there is anything reasonable I can do make my queries safer, or is it out of my hands with prepared statements.

If it is this easy, why is SQL injection still a thing? Shouldn't it have gone the way of polio?

Comment: It's safe because it doesn't pass it into the string to be interpreted, which means that you cannot "escape" the string so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not necessary to sanitize inputs when using prepared statement to protect `sql` injections but you may do it if you want for any other reason.

> If it is this easy, why is SQL injection still a thing? Shouldn't it have gone the way of polio?

it's easy for those who knows about it, nothing is easy unless you know it. I believe `sql` injection doesn't happen a lot nowadays.

Comment: SQL injection happens way more than you believe it to. I have first hand experience with this in my current position of employment, and can attest to the fact that many developers don't secure their code and get destroyed on their "custom contact forms". Furthermore, the **reason** why it's secure is because the actual input from the user is never directly injected into the string. The `prepare` sends the request to the server, the `execute` passes the variables. This allows for a separation and makes it so that it is a non issue.

Comment: I didn't heard about it for a long time but I could be wrong, anyways, thanks:-)

Answer (score 1):

Your example is completely safe because it passes the user input parameters separate from the query string. The reason sql injection still exists is because a lot of users still use the deprecated `mysql_*` api/driver and are unaware of the alternatives. Also, even using pdo or mysqli you can still pass user input directly into the query string instead of binding it separately.